# char [length] initialization and dealing with it

Tags: c, c-strings

I have defined a char array:

```
char d[6];
```

Correct me if I'm wrong regarding following:

At this moment no memory is allocated for variable `d`. Now I'm going to initialize it:

```
d="aaaaa";
```

After this kind of initialization, there would be no need to free memory; it will be done automatically.

How do I know if the `char[]` was initialized? I am looking for a pattern like

```
if (filled(d)){..}
```

Also, how do I fill char[] with one kind of character?

Comment: As soon as you do this `char d[6];`, it allocates 6 bytes for `d`, but it is not initialized.

Comment: Freeing memory is a method which only applies to `malloc`/`calloc`. Deleting memory is a method which only applies to `new`. If you have not used either of these methods you do not need to *free* or *delete* any memory.

Answer (score 6):

> At this moment no memory allocated for variable d.

Incorrect. This:

```
char d[6];
```

is an uninitialised array of 6 `char`s and memory, on stack, has been allocated for it. Stack variables do not need to be explicitly `free()`d, whether they are initialised or not. The memory used by a stack variable will be released when it goes out of scope. Only pointers obtained via `malloc()`, `realloc()` or `calloc()` should be passed to `free()`.

To initialise:

```
char d[6] = "aaaaa"; /* 5 'a's and one null terminator. */
```

or:

```
char d[] = "aaaaa"; /* The size of the array is inferred. */
```

And, as already noted by [mathematician1975](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1342730/mathematician1975), array assignment is illegal:

```
char d[] = "aaaaa"; /* OK, initialisation. */
d = "aaaaa";        /* !OK, assignment. */
```

`strcpy()`, `strncpy()`, `memcpy()`, `snprintf()`, etc can be used to copy into `d` after declaration, or assignment of `char` to individual elements of `d`.

---

> How to know was char[] initialized? I need pattern if filled(d){..}

If the arrays are null terminated you can use `strcmp()`

```
if (0 == strcmp("aaaaaa", d))
{
    /* Filled with 'a's. */
}
```

or use `memcmp()` if not null terminated:

```
if (0 == memcmp("aaaaaa", d, 6))
{
    /* Filled with 'a's. */
}
```

---

> How to fill char[] with one kind of characters?

Use `memset()`:

```
memset(d, 'a', sizeof(d)); /* WARNING: no null terminator. */
```

or:

```
char d[] = { 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a' }; /* Again, no null. */
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not compile (gcc 4.6.3) if you do

```
 char d[6];
 d = "aaaaa";
```

you will need to do

```
 char d[6] = "aaaaa"
```

to initialise it this way.
This is a local variable created on the stack and so in terms of memory issues all you need worry about is not writing/reading beyond the array bounds.

Comment: Best to avoid the term `free`d, as the memory is not allocated with `malloc` internally. The top of the stack is merely moved.

Comment: I'm using c++ for experiment. But my c++ compiler is absolutely happy with lines:
 `char d[6];
 d = "aaaaa";`

Comment: Well you tagged this as a C question, but regardless both my gcc and g++ fail to compile the code above in my answer spread on two lines.

Comment: ok, it is my fault, you are right - `char d[6];` not allowed, soory for that

Answer (score 0):

First, whenever you declare `char d[6]` 6 bytes of memory is already allocated.

Second, no need to free your memory unless you do malloc

Third, if you want to initialize it with one kind of character then do this

```
char d[6] = "aaaaa";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int d[6];
```

6 bytes will be allocated onto the stack with this declaration. It will be freed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
How to know was char[] initialized? I need pattern if filled(d){..}
```

Just do this while declaring the character array:

```
char d[6];
d[0] = 0;
```

Then you can check like this:

```
if(strlen(d) == 0)
//d is not initialized
```