# initialization of char [] and working with it. I don't want to use "string"

Tags: c, c-strings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [char [length] initialization and dealing with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632295/char-length-initialization-and-dealing-with-it)

I have:

```
char d[7];
```

What is wrong regarding following:

At this moment no memory allocated for variable `d`. Now I'm going to initialize it:

```
d="bbbbbb";
```

After this type initialization, there would be no need to free memory; it will be done automatically.

How to know was `char[]` initialized? I need a pattern like

```
if (filled(d)){..}
```

How to fill `char[]` with one kind of characters?

Comment: This is exactly what you asked a few minutes ago?

Comment: I updated your tags to C since you wouldn't use `char[]` in C++.

Comment: in C you can only init an array when you declare it. Like this:       char d[7] = "111111"; This is true for all types of arrays, not only char arrays.

Comment: @DigitalDA Or char `d[6] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };`.

Comment: I'm asking regarding c++, because my c++ compiler allows to write `char d [5];`. As I understood from my previous topic it is not allowed by C compiler. In this topic I expect different answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK if you want to fill your char with 'b' character you CAN do it this way

```
  char d[7];
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      d[i] = 'b';
  }
```